# Configurar tooltip em evento de clique em célula do grid

Tags: grid, tooltip, extjs-4

Estou tentando mostrar uma tooltip quando o usuário clicar em uma célula do grid. Quando eu clico em uma célula, a tooltip aparece. O problema é que, após o clique, ela fica aparecendo sempre que eu passo o mouse sobre qualquer outra célula.
Estou usando Ext JS 4.2.1. 
Deixarei abaixo o código de como estou tratando o evento cellclick no controller e a forma como estou criando a tooltip.

```
onCellClick: function (view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('pontoeletronico');        
    if (view.tip) {
        view.tip.destroy();                        
        view.tip = null;            
    }        
    if(cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < 5) {
        view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            autoShow: false,
            showDelay: 0,                                    
            stateful: false,
            target: view.el,
            width: 100,
            title: 'Horário original',
            delegate: view.cellSelector,
            trackMouse: false,
            autoHide: true,
            listeners: {
                beforeshow: function (tooltip, eOpts) {
                    var ponto = store.findRecord('id', record.get('idPonto'));
                    var horario;
                    if (cellIndex == 1) {
                        horario = ponto.get('entrada01');                        
                    } else if (cellIndex = 2) {
                        horario = ponto.get('saida01');                        
                    } else if (cellIndex == 3) {
                        horario = ponto.get('entrada02');                        
                    } else if (cellIndex == 4) {
                        horario = ponto.get('saida02');                        
                    }
                    horario = horario != null ? Ext.Date.format(horario, 'H:i:s') : "--:--:--";                    
                    //tooltip.update(horario);
                    tooltip.html = horario;                    

                }                
            }
        });
    }                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução para o meu problema, mas deixarei em aberto para o caso de alguém dar uma solução melhor.

Bom, para que a tooltip só aparecesse quando eu clicasse e sumisse quando eu movesse o mouse, adicionei um evento no controller chamado **itemmouseleave**. Desta forma, quando o item, sob o qual o mouse está, mudar eu destruo a tooltip adicionada àquela view. O código final ficou da seguinte forma:

```
onItemMouseLeave: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    if (view.tip) {
        view.tip.destroy();
    }  
},

onCellClick: function (view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('pontoeletronico');        
    if (view.tip) {
        view.tip.destroy();                        
        view.tip = null;            
    }        
    if(cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < 5) {            
        view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            itemId: 'tooltip-horario',
            autoShow: false,
            showDelay: 0,                                    
            stateful: false,
            target: view.el,
            width: 100,
            title: 'Horário original',
            delegate: view.cellSelector,
            trackMouse: false,
            autoHide: true
        });
        var ponto = store.findRecord('id', record.get('idPonto'));
        var horario;
        if (cellIndex == 1) {
            horario = ponto.get('entrada01');                        
        } else if (cellIndex = 2) {
            horario = ponto.get('saida01');                        
        } else if (cellIndex == 3) {
            horario = ponto.get('entrada02');                        
        } else if (cellIndex == 4) {
            horario = ponto.get('saida02');                        
        }
        horario = horario != null ? Ext.Date.format(horario, 'H:i:s') : "--:--:--";                    
        view.tip.update(horario);                                     
    }                              
}
```